# Why the type of size_t is uint in 64-bit Windows 7?

Tags: d

I am a newbie of programming `D`. After reading [Fundamental Types](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/types.html), I decide to check the `size_t` type in my `64`-bit Windows 7 OS. The code is like this:

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    writeln("Type: ", size_t.stringof);
    writeln("Size: ", size_t.sizeof);
}
```

After executing, the output is:

```
Type: uint
Size: 4
```

Per my understanding, the type of `size_t` should be ulong on `64`-bit OS.
Could anyone give any clue? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Possible you are running a 32 bit process?

Comment: Are you compiling a 64-bit program? Keep in mind that you saying you're on a 64-bit OS does not answer that question.

Comment: @hvd:After using "`dmd -v`" command, it displays "`DMD32 D Compiler v2.066.1`". Ithink it means this `dmd` only can compile 32-bit code, right?

Comment: Use the `-m64` option to produce a 64-bit executable.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: After executing "`dmd hello.d -m64`" command, it displays: "`Can't run '\bin\link.exe', check PATH`". So I think 'DMD32' can't build 64-bit program.

Comment: The 64 bit build needs the Microsoft linker installed and dmd configured to find it, whereas the 32 bit one works out of the box (it brings its own linker). So 64 bit can be done, it just needs a bit more work. What I did recently was install the new community version of Visual Studio from MS - now offered free - and then run the dmd installer exe afterward. It mostly auto configured (I still had to enter the c:\D path at one point but the rest just worked) and then can do 32 and 64 bit easy with -m32 or -m64.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bitness of your program is distinct from the bitness of the OS or the compiler.

With DMD, to create a 64-bit executable, specify the `-m64` switch. By default, DMD will create programs with the same bitness as the compiler, and the Windows package includes a 32-bit compiler. (If you wish, you can also build a 64-bit compiler from source code, but this will not affect how it builds either 32-bit or 64-bit programs.)